# What's wrong with order for not() in python?

Tags: python, operators, boolean-expression

What's wrong with using not() in python?. I tried this

```
    In [1]: not(1) + 1
    Out[1]: False
```

And it worked fine. But after readjusting it,

```
    In [2]: 1 + not(1)
    Out[2]: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It gives an error. How does the order matters?

Comment: `not` is not a function..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`not` is a [*unary operator*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations), not a function, so please don't use the `(..)` call notation on it. The parentheses are ignored when parsing the expression and `not(1) + 1` is the same thing as `not 1 + 1`.

Due to precedence rules Python tries to parse the second expression as:

```
1 (+ not) 1
```

which is invalid syntax. If you really must use `not` after `+`, use parentheses:

```
1 + (not 1)
```

For the same reasons, `not 1 + 1` first calculates `1 + 1`, then applies `not` to the result.

Comment: Can you tell why `False + 1` returns `False` ?

Comment: @VivekSable: because `bool` is a subclass of `int`, with `True` equal to 1 and `False` equal to 0. Like all numbers they are then coerced to a more complex type when used in arithmetic (same as `1.0 + 1` gives `2.0`).

Comment: @VivekSable: and `False + 1` returns `1`, not `False`.

Comment: Yes, `False + 1` return `1` and `not(1) + 1` return `False`

Comment: @VivekSable: because that's `not ((1) + 1)`, so `not 2`, and `2` is a true value, so the inverse is `False`. If you wanted `not` to apply to just the first `1`, you need to use `(not 1) + 1`. Again, `not` is *not a function*.